# Java - JLabel background isn't fully transparent?

Tags: java, image, transparency, transparent, jlabel

I have a JLabel with a box icon on it. I create the icon's image in photoshop. It's a png-24 image with the background full erased.

But when moved on top of a dark background, you can see that the background isn't fully transparent:

[image]

---

EDIT #2:

The image IS transparent. I've even gone through photoshop tutorials to make sure I'm creating a transparent image the correct way. The problem seems to be with Java (and JLabels).

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: if the image ***IS*** transparent then why doesn't it show up as transparent in an html page?

Answer (score 3):

i've tested your image, it is not transparent. surely that is the reason.

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:#99cccc;">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>your one isn't transparent</th>
        <th>this one is</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvYxM.png" style="border:5px solid green;"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://www.axdn.com/redist/axpssp_logo.png" style="border:5px solid green;"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

@Gabe: paste this into a html file and load it in a browser. This clearly isn't an issue with anything java related.

here's a java proof that your image isn't transparent AND that a proper transparent PNG works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.setBackground(Color.RED);
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    cp.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvYxM.png"))));
    cp.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.axdn.com/redist/axpssp_logo.png"))));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: How can I fix it then? I erase all of the background in photoshop? It seems like Java handles the image differently.

Comment: Use File / Save for Web to save the PNG with transparency.

Comment: @Gabe "It seems like Java handles the image differently" - you're missing the point. the image is not transparent. nothing to do with java. you should be reading the photoshop help or using another program. see edit.

Comment: i'm sure he did it as "transparency" inside the Photoshop.
as I also did.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with GIF format and set alpha value accordingly.
I could not see your image right now.
Well, make sure image that you are creating that is transparent.
Otherwise you would not get it as you need.

sample guide for making transparent image: [LINK](http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/transparent/gif.html)

Comment: That didn't work either. I know it has to be a PNG. (I've read before that Java transparenc only works with PNG's.)

Comment: hey.... i think i encountered the same thing here.
once my png shown OK first, but when I repaint it over, it gives me black background also.... so then, how to fix it out? :(